# regular Borel probability measure implying countable basis

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Peter Walters' An Introduction to Ergodic Theory (page 10) says

> If $X$ is a metric space and ($\mathscr{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$... and $m$ is any probability measure on $(X, \mathscr{B})$ then $(X, \mathscr{B},m)$ has a countable basis. (This follows from Theorem 6.1.) Therefore most of the spaces we shall deal with have $L^2(X, \mathscr{B}, m)$ separable.

**I do not see why $(X, \mathscr{B},m)$ has a countable basis.**

- Here, $(X, \mathscr{B},m)$ is said to have a countable basis if there exists a sequence of elements $\{E_n\}_n^\infty\subset \mathscr{B}$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $B\in\mathscr{B}$ with $m(B)<\infty$ there is some $n$ with
  $$
  m(B\triangle E_n)=m(B\setminus E_n)+m(E_n\setminus B)<\epsilon.
  $$
- Theorem 6.1:

> (Theorem 6.1) A Borel probability measure $m$ on a metric space $X$ is regular (i.e., $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}(X)$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ an open set $U_\epsilon$, and a closed set $C_\epsilon$, with $C_\epsilon\subset B\subset U_\epsilon$ and $m(U_\epsilon\setminus C_\epsilon) < \epsilon$).

---

---

**(Thoughts)**
For any $\epsilon>0$ and for any $B\in\mathscr{B}(X)$, we can take $U_\epsilon$, $C_\epsilon$ as above such that
$$
m(B\setminus C_\epsilon)\leq m(U_\epsilon\setminus C_\epsilon) < \epsilon
$$
and
$$
m(C_\epsilon\setminus B)=m(\emptyset)=0
$$
but I do not see how only countably many $C_\epsilon$ would suffice.

What is still confusing is that on page 45 Walters say

> If $X$ is a metric space with a countable topological base and $\mathscr{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$ then $(X, \mathscr{B},m)$ has a countable basis for any probability measure $m$ on $(X,\mathscr{B})$. This follows from Theorem 6.1.

Now we have an extra condition on $X$...

Comment: It seems clear that $X$ being second countable(or equivalently, separable) is necessary for this.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Ok but now even with a countable base, I do not know how to fix $\{E_n\}_n^\infty$. We have $$m(B\triangle U_\epsilon)=m(B\setminus U_\epsilon) +m(U_\epsilon\setminus B)=0+m(U_\epsilon\setminus B)\leq m(U_\epsilon\setminus C_\epsilon)<\epsilon,$$ and we know we can describe $U_\epsilon$ as a union of at most countable open sets, but $\epsilon$ is arbitrary...

Answer (score 1):

The standard Borel measure on the compact double arrow space ($[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ ordered lexicographically) is a separable measure (with full support) on a space that is *not* second countable. (All finite Borel measures with full support on compact ordered spaces are separable, as shown by Kunen et al.)

Comment: [This](https://archive.uea.ac.uk/~h020/fundamenta.pdf) paper is on the compact spaces *all* of whose  (probability Borel) measures are separable. It is a far larger class than just metric compacta.

Comment: Thank you, but regarding the wikipedia link, I am failing to relate the original metric of $X$ and the pseudometric induced by the measure.

Comment: @shall.i.am It's not doing that. It just links a metric fact of the $\sigma$-algebra to a topological fact on $X$. Too bad it doesn't give a reference.

Comment: Ah, I might have missed the point of your answer. I thought you meant that in general the metric space $X$ needs to be separable for $(X,\mathscr{B},m)$ to have a countable basis. But this link seems to be saying that if $X$ is equipped with the metric induced by the measure, then the metric space $X$ needs to be separable for $(X,\mathscr{B},m)$ to have a countable basis?

Comment: @shall.i.am The "countable basis" in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is just a dense subset of the metric space induced on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ by $d(A,B)=m(A \Delta B)$. $\mu$ is called a "separable measure" for that reason. It implies that $X$ as a space (it need not even be metrisable, and $m$ does not induce a metric on $X$ e.g.)  is also separable. And *then* if you *know* $X$ is metrisable it must then be second countable. Don't get confused..

Comment: Ah ok. Is the statement you seem to be saying the following?
"Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Suppose $\mathcal{B}(X)$ has a countable basis. Then, $X$ is separable."  
(I did not get this from the wikipedia link and I am trying to reconcile).

Comment: @shall.i.am yes, and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ has a countable base is usually called “$\mu$ is separable “

Comment: Nice! Also, pity they don't give a reference indeed...

Comment: I think this is trivially false.  Let $X$ be your favorite non-separable metric space and let $m$ be a point mass at some point $x_0$.  The measure space consists of exactly two equivalence classes (sets that contain $x_0$ and sets that don't) and the pseudometric $\rho(A,B) = \mu(A \triangle B)$ is the discrete metric, so the measure space is trivially separable.

Comment: A plausible statement might be that if the measure space is separable then the *support* of $m$ is a separable subset of $X$.  But I am not sure whether this is true.